# How to implement data rewriting in a json file?

Tags: python, json

I have a json file:

```
[{dic_1},{dic_2},{dic_3},{dic_4}]
```

how to optimally add a new dictionary {dic_5} to the file at the end to make it work:

```
[{dic_1},{dic_2},{dic_3},{dic_4}, {dic_5}]
```

At the same time, the file may be empty...

I'm trying:

```
with open('path/file.json', "r+") as file:
    json.dump(dic_5, file)
```

or this:

```
tmp =[]
with open("path/file.json", "r") as f1:
    tmp.append(json.load(f1))
    tmp.append(dic_5)
with open("path/file.json", "w") as f2:
    json.dump(tmp, f2)
    f2.write('\n')
```

But it doesn't work (dictionaries are just added and the json file is obtained with an error, because there is no list, no commas, etc.)
it turns out anything, just not what I need: `[{},{},{},{},{}]`

Comment: Load the JSON file, append the new dict to the list, dump the updated JSON file.

Comment: The update doesn't make this question not a duplicate, it just makes this two different questions: the first is a duplicate, the second is under-described (what error?).

Answer (score 0):

`json.dump(dic_5, file)` is dumping a dictionary, and doesn't know this file has a list.

You need to read the file using `json.load`, which returns a list, then you need to `.append(dic_5)`, after which, you can `json.dump(your_list, file)` (in `open("...", "w")` mode so that you are effectively overwriting the file content with a new list)